# What value does this Javascript function factory add?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I stumbled upon this block of code and don't really see the need for returning a function when the outer function doesn't take any arguments?

```
var percent = (function() {
    var fmt = d3.format(".2f");
    return function(n) { return fmt(n) + "%"; };
})()
```

Am I missing something or can it be rewritten as:

```
var percent = function(n) {
    return d3.format(".2f")(n) + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can, but then you are calling `d3.format(".2f")` each time instead of once only. Depending on what the function is doing and how often it is called, this could add an additional performance overhead.

With the IIEF (*immediately invoked function expression*) returning the closure, you are "caching" `fmt` for all future uses of `percent`.

Comment: Ahh, it is the caching. Thanks.